# Wrong A4 measurements?

Tags: document-classes, paper-size, geometry

I noticed that the paper size invoked by `a4paper` is not working right in my examples:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,oneside]{article}
\begin{document}
Test
\end{document}
```

I checked with Preview.app and it tells me the paper size is 21.59 cm × 27.94 cm.
A4 should be 21.0 cm × 29.7 cm.

When I use `\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}` I notice a different size of the paper (it gets narrower) and Preview.app says: 21.01 cm × 29.71 cm, which seems right.
I can reproduce this exact behavior with every class: `article`, `book` etc., `scrartcl`, `scrreprt`, etc., `g-brief2` except `memoir` which gives me 21.01 cm x 29.71 cm

Is there something wrong or am I missing something?

Comment: Whait, the KOMA-classes give you the right or wrong size?

Comment: scrartcl etc. give me the wrong size

Comment: Try using the option `pagesize` when using the KOMA-Script classes.

Comment: Do you create a `.dvi` file from the `.tex` input and then run `dvips` etc to create the pdf file you then view in Preview? If so, check the settings in dvips -- it they may be the case that it's set to always create output with a page size of "US Letter" (8.5" x 11").

Comment: well I use pdfLaTeX but I tried every other typeset chain I know of (including XeLaTeX and LaTeX > dvips > ps2pdf) and it doesn't change anything

Comment: Just for the record, `memoir` sets the paper size to the values corresponding to `\stocksize`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The `a4paper` option of the standard classes don't actually set the PDF page size, just the size which is used to set the text. That's why you should always use `geometry` if your class doesn't do that automatically. Most other classes do that by default as you see.

So no, there's nothing wrong and you aren't really missing anything.

If your page size in KOMA-Script is wrong, try using the `pagesize` option.

Comment: `pagesize` works for KOMA. Thanks! What's weird is that classes like `g-brief2` which is for a DIN-Letter gives me the wrong size

Comment: Probably you mean `\usepackage[pass]{geometry}`, unless one wants to pass other parameters to it.

Answer (score 8):

With MacTeX it's possible to choose, at installation time, the default paper size for all engines. The choice can be reverted with TeX Live Utility: the "Configure" menu has the entry "Change Paper Size…".

Alternatively, the setting can be changed from the command line, by issuing

```
sudo tlmgr paper a4
```

or

```
sudo tlmgr paper letter
```

The paper format can even be set differently for each "engine", for example

```
sudo tlmgr pdftex paper a4
```

would set A4 paper only for `pdftex` based formats (so also `pdflatex`).

One can also state the paper size on a per-document basis: it's sufficient to say

```
\usepackage[pass,a4paper]{geometry}
```

to get output on A4 paper (independently of the engine used for compiling the document). Of course, the `pass` option must not be used if one wants to set other dimensions with `geometry`. The package will perform the appropriate steps for the typesetting engine used (`latex+dvips`, `pdflatex`, `xelatex` or `lualatex`).

---

Note that the `tlmgr` commands are valid for any TeX Live distribution on every system supporting it (the `sudo` prefix might be inappropriate on some systems).

Answer (score 6):

From [The Not So Short Introduction to LaTeX2ε](http://tobi.oetiker.ch/lshort/lshort.pdf):

> Set the paper size with an optional documentclass argument such as
>   `a4paper` or `letterpaper`. This works in pdfLaTeX too, but on top of
>   this pdfTeX also needs to know the physical size of the paper to
>   determine the physical size of the pages in the pdf file. If you use
>   the `hyperref` package (see page 93), the papersize will be adjusted
>   automatically. Otherwise you have to do this manually by putting the
>   following lines into the preamble of the document:
>
> `\pdfpagewidth=\paperwidth`
>
> `\pdfpageheight=\paperheight`

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I use MacTeX 2012 and using `texconfig pdftex paper a4` in the Terminal works globally for pdfLaTeX.

For XeLaTeX `xelatex -papersize=a4 index.tex` works per document but a global option would be nice.

Am I the only one that thinks this bevavior is kind of strange?

Comment: `texconfig` is an obsolete script; the right way for MacTeX (TeX Live) is `sudo tlmgr paper a4` that will set the format for all engines.

Comment: With `sudo tlmgr paper a4` even XeLaTeX works. nice

Answer (score 1):

running your example with `pdflatex` or `xelatex` gives:

```
voss@shania:~/Test> pdfinfo Namenlos-4.pdf
Creator:        TeX
Producer:       pdfTeX-1.40.12
CreationDate:   Thu Aug  9 13:06:20 2012
ModDate:        Thu Aug  9 13:06:20 2012
Tagged:         no
Pages:          1
Encrypted:      no
Page size:      595.276 x 841.89 pts (A4)
File size:      10796 bytes
Optimized:      no
PDF version:    1.5
```

that are correct values for A4. Also Acrobat shows with its properties 210 × 297

Comment: If you're using MiKTeX, it may depend on your setting for "default paper format" if I remember correct.