# How to place a background image on page (using tikz?) that goes behind everything

Tags: tikz-pgf, header-footer, backgrounds

I want to place an image behind everything on a specific page in my document to liven it up a bit. The first I tried to do was to do was put in a tikz-picture as background, and it worked pretty well, but infortunately the header gets drawn over.

Here is the essential code I have used so far, and its output:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside]{scrbook}
\RequirePackage{microtype}
\RequirePackage{pdfpages}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{multicol}

% Dimensions:
\setlength\topmargin{-58pt}                 
\setlength\headheight{20pt}                 
\setlength\headsep{25pt}                 
\setlength\marginparwidth{-20pt}            
\setlength\textwidth{\paperwidth - 82pt}    
\setlength\textheight{\paperheight - 112pt} 
\setlength\oddsidemargin{-30pt}
\setlength\evensidemargin{-30pt}

% Header and Footer:
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
% Header
\lhead[\thepage]{Edition}
\rhead[Name]{\thepage}
\chead{\sffamily HEADER}
% Headercolour
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}% 2pt header rule
\renewcommand{\headrule}{\hbox to\headwidth{%
\color{black}\leaders\hrule height \headrulewidth\hfill}}
% Footer
\lfoot{}
\rfoot{}
\cfoot{\vspace{-20pt}\textcolor{black}{\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}}}

% Fonts:
\usepackage{mathptmx}   % Serif
\usepackage{DejaVuSans} % Sans-serif
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xstring}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node (background) at (0.5\textwidth,-0.5\textheight+15pt) {\includegraphics[height=\paperheight+20pt]{bak}};
\draw [white , fill=white, opacity=0.7](-15pt,-\topmargin+5pt) rectangle (\textwidth+10pt,-\topmargin-\headheight-10pt);
\draw [white , fill=white, opacity=0.7](-15pt,15pt) rectangle (\textwidth+10pt,-\textheight);
\draw [white , fill=white, opacity=0.7](-15pt,-\textheight-22pt) rectangle (\textwidth+10pt,-\textheight-30pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\lettrine[loversize=0.1]{A}{S} I said, this is a test. \lipsum
\end{multicols}
\clearpage

\begin{multicols}{2}
\lipsum
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

[image: The output]

Notice that of the two pages, only the second has a header. In the other the tikz-picture has drawn on top of it. If there is some way to make tikz draw underneath the header, or even to force a re-draw of the header, that would solve my problems. But I do not know how to do any of these.

Notice also that the footer *does* show up, whereas the header disappears behind the tikz drawing, for some reason. I don't know what to make of this.

Any ideas?

Comment: did you try the background package

Comment: Or the wallpaper package.  (Google latex wallpaper showed the most amazing pictures!)

Comment: @touhami No, does it do what I want?

Comment: @JohnKormylo Where can I find some examples of the wallpaper package in use? Also, is it capable of doing something like my example (with rectangles of color and opacity, only for chosen pages, etc)?

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/110502/how-to-make-an-image-for-backgrounds-with-exact-a4-dimensions?rq=1 The foreground of partially opaque filler might be more difficult, although you could just edit it onto the picture.

Comment: Why use a KOMA class if you then cripple it by using `geometry` and `fancyhdr`?

Comment: `background` is more powerful. `wallpaper` is easier to use. Yes, they can do what you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a suggestion that needs an uptodate KOMA-Script: version 3.16 or newer. Then you can use `scrlayer-scrpage` instead `fancyhdr` and define a new pagestyles for the pages with a background image.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside]{scrbook}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{multicol}

% Dimensions:
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
  top=59pt,
  headheight=20pt,
  headsep=20pt,
  bottom=53pt,
  footskip=50pt,
  %marginparwidth=-20pt,
  hmargin=41pt
  }

\addtokomafont{pagehead}{\normalfont}
\usepackage[headsepline=1pt,footsepline=1pt]{scrlayer-scrpage}%<- activates pagestyle scrheadings
\clearpairofpagestyles
\newcommand*{\headcontents}[1]{%
  \raisebox{0pt}[\ht\strutbox][\dimexpr\headheight-\ht\strutbox\relax]{#1}}
\lehead{\headcontents{\pagemark}}
\lohead{\headcontents{Edition}}
\rehead{\headcontents{Name}}
\rohead{\headcontents{\pagemark}}
\chead{\sffamily\headcontents{HEADER}}

\newpairofpagestyles[scrheadings]{backgroundimage}{}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*\@backgroundimage{}
\newcommand*\backgroundimage[1]{%
  \ifstr{#1}{}{\gdef\@backgroundimage{}}{%
    \gdef\@backgroundimage{\includegraphics[height=\dimexpr\paperheight+20pt\relax]{#1}}%
}}

\colorlet{backgroundcolor}{white}
\newcommand*\coloredbg{%
  \tikz\fill[backgroundcolor,opacity=.7](0,0)rectangle({\layerwidth},{\layerheight});}

\DeclareNewLayer[background,textarea,
  addvoffset=-5pt,addhoffset=-5pt,addwidth=10pt,addheight=10pt,
  contents=\coloredbg
]{text.bg}
\DeclareNewLayer[background,foot,align=b,
  addvoffset=9pt,addhoffset=-5pt,addwidth=10pt,height=12pt,
  contents=\coloredbg
]{foot.bg}
\DeclareNewLayer[background,head,
  addvoffset=11pt,addhoffset=-5pt,addwidth=10pt,addheight=13pt,
  contents=\coloredbg
]{head.bg}
\DeclareNewLayer[background,
  area={.5\paperwidth}{.5\paperheight}{0pt}{0pt},
  contents={\makebox[0pt]{%
    \raisebox{0pt}[.5\height][.5\height]{\@backgroundimage}%
  }}
]{image.bg}
\AddLayersAtBeginOfPageStyle{backgroundimage}{text.bg,foot.bg,head.bg,image.bg}
\makeatother

\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{DejaVuSans}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xstring}

\usepackage{mwe}% for the example images

\begin{document}
\backgroundimage{example-image}%<- set the background image
\thispagestyle{backgroundimage}%<- use the background image only on the current page
\begin{multicols}{2}
\lettrine[loversize=0.1]{A}{S} I said, this is a test. \lipsum
\lipsum
\end{multicols}
\clearpage

\backgroundimage{example-image-A}%<- change the background image
\pagestyle{backgroundimage}%<- change the pagestyle
\begin{multicols}{2}
\lipsum\lipsum
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How do I make sure I have such an up to date version of KOMA-script? When might I not have? I want to make a setup that is easy to use for several people, other than myself, who use different setups and LaTeX distributions. Could this cause problems?

Comment: Other than that, let me just add, this solution looks absolutely perfect for my needs.

Comment: 2015/02/07 v3.16 is the current [KOMA-Script](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/koma-script)version on CTAN, in TeX Live 2014 and MiKTeX2.9. Additionally you can get this version from the [KOMA-Script website](http://www.komascript.de/node/1801)

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside]{scrbook}
\RequirePackage{microtype}
\RequirePackage{pdfpages}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{multicol}

% Dimensions:
\setlength\topmargin{-58pt}                 
\setlength\headheight{20pt}                 
\setlength\headsep{25pt}                 
\setlength\marginparwidth{-20pt}            
\setlength\textwidth{\paperwidth - 82pt}    
\setlength\textheight{\paperheight - 112pt} 
\setlength\oddsidemargin{-30pt}
\setlength\evensidemargin{-30pt}

% Header and Footer:
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
% Header
\lhead[\thepage]{Edition}
\rhead[Name]{\thepage}
\chead{\sffamily HEADER}
% Headercolour
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}% 2pt header rule
\renewcommand{\headrule}{\hbox to\headwidth{%
\color{black}\leaders\hrule height \headrulewidth\hfill}}
% Footer
\lfoot{}
\rfoot{}
\cfoot{\vspace{-20pt}\textcolor{black}{\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}}}

% Fonts:
\usepackage{mathptmx}   % Serif
\usepackage{DejaVuSans} % Sans-serif
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xstring}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\def \@begindvi{%
  \unvbox \@begindvibox
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node (background) at (0.5\textwidth,-0.5\textheight+15pt) {\includegraphics[height=\paperheight+20pt]{bak}};
\draw [white , fill=white, opacity=0.7](-15pt,-\topmargin+5pt) rectangle (\textwidth+10pt,-\topmargin-\headheight-10pt);
\draw [white , fill=white, opacity=0.7](-15pt,15pt) rectangle (\textwidth+10pt,-\textheight);
\draw [white , fill=white, opacity=0.7](-15pt,-\textheight-22pt) rectangle (\textwidth+10pt,-\textheight-30pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
  \global\let \@begindvi \@empty
}
\makeatother

\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\lettrine[loversize=0.1]{A}{S} I said, this is a test. 
\lipsum
\end{multicols}
\clearpage

\begin{multicols}{2}
\lipsum
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

**Edit: use this by command** \mtbg{bak}

```
    \def\mtbak#1{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node (background) at (0.5\textwidth,-0.5\textheight+15pt) {\includegraphics[height=\paperheight+20pt]{#1}};
\draw [white , fill=white, opacity=0.7](-15pt,-\topmargin+5pt) rectangle (\textwidth+10pt,-\topmargin-\headheight-10pt);
\draw [white , fill=white, opacity=0.7](-15pt,15pt) rectangle (\textwidth+10pt,-\textheight);
\draw [white , fill=white, opacity=0.7](-15pt,-\textheight-22pt) rectangle (\textwidth+10pt,-\textheight-30pt);
\end{tikzpicture}}
\makeatletter
\def\mtbg#1{%
\def \@begindvi{%
  \unvbox \@begindvibox
  \mtbak{#1}
  \global\let \@begindvi \@empty
}}
\makeatother
```

Comment: That seems to work really well! I only notice a slight problem with the positioning of the tikz-picture. It seems to be indented. In my original code I simply added a `\noindent` to prevent this, but this doesn't seem to work here. Any ideas?

Comment: Also, I can't seem to make this solution into a macro, which is something I would like to do to make things easier. A command `\background{bak}` that takes the picture name.

Comment: @Deltat for the position you maybe need to move your objects to the left for example replace (-15pt,-\topmargin+5pt) by (-15pt-.5cm,-\topmargin+5pt)